# Uploading photos or videos to Facebook using Python

Tags: python, facebook, video, upload

I tried to upload photos or videos to facebook page using Python but I got 
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. But it was Ok when I used form instead.
let me show you the codes.

This is code for form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="https://graph-video.facebook.com/videos/PAGE_ID/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"  
 method="POST">
<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and This is my Python code.

```
video = open(args[0])

url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/videos/PAGE_ID'
    data = {'access_token': 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
            'title': 'test',
            'description': 'test',
            'source' : video
           }
    data1 = urllib.urlencode(data) 
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data1)
    r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I think that access_token is not the issue since it worked when I used form.

please let me know how to upload videos or photos by Python. thanks.

Comment: My guess is that your issue is coming from the `enctype` part which is missing in your second request (Python).

Answer (score 5):

This works for me.

```
 import requests
 url='https://graph-video.facebook.com/100000198728296/videos?access_token='+str(access)
 path="/home/abc.mp4"
 files={'file':open(path,'rb')}
 flag=requests.post(url, files=files).text
 print flag
```

flag will return **json** containing video id on successful upload of video